# OpenSuse Tumbleweed regulary becomes unresponsive (maybe/probably caused by Chrome)

Tags: opensuse, chrome

I am using the latest OpenSuse Tumbleweed with a Lenovo ThinkPad, AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon Graphics and 16GB RAM and am constantly facing issues with the *complete system* freezing to unresponsiveness. Sometimes it comes back. Sometimes I am forced to turn it off and on again. I mainly use

- Chrome (with MS Teams / constant calls)
- VS Code (with nodejs / jest)

I tried:

- monitoring the use
- turning off swap
- turning off hardware acceleration for VS Code.

Unfortunately I don't know much about Linux configuration so I don't know where to start debugging this issue.

Any help is appreciated. I don't want to go back to Windows!

**EDIT:** `top` show `kswapd0` running amok. I turned swap off using `swapoff -a` so I am not sure what business kswapd has but at least that seems like a known problem

Comment: This sounds like a memory issue, turning off swap won't have any effect if there isn't enough memory. With the `top` command you can type "M" and sort for memory consumption, maybe there are processes running that aren't required but still consume lots of memory?

Comment: Thanks @eblock - yeah it turned out "turn off swap" was suggested by a guy with 32GB of RAM :-D --- so I did the opposite now and created a 16Gig swapfile. We'll see how that goes